# Is it possible to derive a homomorphic signature from homomorphic encryption

Tags: encryption, signature, homomorphic-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

At the moment I am trying to find a practical way to implement a linearly homomorphic signature.

Background:

"In a homomorphic signature scheme, a user Alice signs some large dataset x using her secret signing key and uploads the signed data to an untrusted remote server. The server can then run some computation y=f(x) over the signed data and homomorphically derive a short signature σf,y certifying that y is the correct output of the computation f. Anybody can verify the tuple (f,y,σf,y) using Alice's public verification key and become convinced of this fact without having to retrieve the entire underlying data."

At the moment I can't find anything in the literature, but it seems like it should be possible to implement a homomorphic signature using homomorphic encryption. Specifically, I want to use Microsoft SEAL to do this.

It looks like it should be possible (and quite simple) to implement all the required components of a linearly homomorphic signature using microsoft SEAL. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: [Homomorphic Signature Schemes - A Survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d25/419e80fff2599c47d5c86f77ebe717feb534.pdf)

Comment: Hi Kelalaka, thanks for the reply. However, I read the paper and it doesn't address homomorphic encryption or whether homomorphic signatures can be constructed using homomorphic encryption. What are your thoughts regarding this aspect? Thanks!